# Error when enabling remote data archive on SQL Server 2014 sp2 instance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database, stretch

I am beginning to deploy a stretch database feature for a database on SQL Server 2014 dev edition instance locally. As a prerequisite for the stretch database feature enabling as mentioned on learn.microsoft.com, one has to enable Stretch Database on a server (in my case the SQL Server 2014 dev instance).

The T-SQL to do this is:

```
EXEC sp_configure N'remote data archive' , '1';  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

However, I get this error:

[image]

The advanced option is already enabled on my SQL Server instance.

I am not sure whether this error is related to my SQL Server instance (dev) or my SSMS (17.8). Please if someone could highlight me as to if I am doing anything wrong or whether is there some other prerequisite which needs enabling to utilize this stretch database feature.

I have read that the Stretch database feature was enabled starting from SQL Server 2012 SP1 CU2 edition so this should not be an issue with SQL Server 2014 and that Dev edition is similar to Enterprise edition.

Comment: The "Stretch Database" feature was introduced in SQL Server **2016** - it is *not* available in 2014 - regardless of what edition you're using

Comment: Ah! I see. Thank you marc_s

Comment: Check this: https://sqlperformance.com/2015/08/sql-server-2016/intro-stretch-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, indeed the "Stretch Database" feature was introduced in SQL Server 2016 (CTP) as mentioned by marc_s....... and would not work with my local SQL Server 2014 edition. I had further examined my SQL server 2014 advanced options features list by running this below query (source SQL Authority blog) on my sql server 2014 edition and did not find the 'remote data archive' feature within the list of names.

```
EXEC sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
EXEC sp_configure;
```

As I couldn't tick mark marc_s response, I am posting my own answer with thanks to marc.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below explanation and fix for your problem.

**Error**:- Msg 15123, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_configure, Line 51
The configuration option ‘optimize for ad hoc workloads’ does not exist, or it may be an advanced option.

**Fix**:- This error is happening due to not enabling advance option. Therefore you have to run complete following script and it will fix the problem.

```
sp_CONFIGURE 'show advanced options',1
RECONFIGURE
GO

sp_configure N'remote data archive' , '1';  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```